# PHP: Escape illegal chars in .ini-files

Tags: php, ini

The documentation on [parse_ini_file](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-ini-file.php) states that you can't use these chars `{}|&~![()^"` in the value. Is there some way to escape these chars? I need to use them. Normal escaping with \ doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Any reason why keys would need these characters, especially &?

Comment: I hope you aren't doing this for security.

Answer (score 20):

The [manual](http://uk.php.net/parse_ini_file) says those characters can not be used in the **key** -- the opposite of the **value**. To use them in values, double-quote the string.

Comment: "Characters {}|&~![()^" must not be used anywhere in the key and have a special meaning in the value."

Okay not forbidden but it doesn't parse if i put a () in a double-quoted string value.

Comment: What about double quotes?

Comment: Double quoted string does not work the same way if they span multiple lines - then, they work like not quoted string, just with newlines

Answer (score 6):

Try using `INI_SCANNER_RAW` (from the same documentation) for `scanner_mode`:

```
parse_ini_file ( $filename, true, INI_SCANNER_RAW );
```

Comment: This can work if you happen to parse your own `.ini` file for your own usage. This will not cover the case where you change a `.ini` that is consumed by some other code (including the `.ini` that are read at PHP start).